# Setting HTTP_REFERER for URLS on webpages?

Tags: java, javascript, http, http-headers

I have a webpage which refers other pages.

I want to be able to set the HTTP_REFERER on the URL's that are clicked.

What options do I have?

Comment: isnt it auto set by browsers?

Comment: Host your website on that URL.

Comment: I sniffed the requests reaching the other pages - and did not see the referer being set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What options do I have?

None really. The browser sets this automatically.

The only thing you can do is redirect to a script (under your control) like

```
http://example.com/redirect.php?url=........
```

That file (in this case, PHP) would then do a header redirect to the target, and show up in the receiving site's HTTP_REFERER header.

Also, linking to a `https://` page from a `http://` one or vice versa will **drop** the referrer. See the Wikipedia article on [referrer hiding.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer)

Other than that, there is nothing you can do to alter it. There is definitely no way to set it to an arbitrary value from within a web site.

Comment: never knew about the case of linking from an `http` to an `https`. +1